# Laravel10, Interia, svelte setting shows warning

Tags: laravel, svelte

I'm new to svelte and Interia.
I've setup an application with Laravel10,Interia and svelte.

app.ts goes like

```
import { createInertiaApp } from "@inertiajs/svelte";

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: (name) => {
        const pages = import.meta.glob("./components/pages/**/*.svelte", {
            eager: true,
        });

        return pages[`./components/pages/${name}.svelte`];
    },

    setup({ el, App, props }) {
        console.log(el, App, props)
        new App({ target: el, props });
    },
});
```

the application is working well. But it shows several warnings in console. Is it ignorable?

```
14:47:08.566 <App> was created with unknown prop 'initialPage' @inertiajs_svelte.js:6629:15
14:47:08.566 <App> was created with unknown prop 'resolveComponent' @inertiajs_svelte.js:6629:15
14:47:08.566 <Index> received an unexpected slot "default". index.mjs:2380:20
14:47:08.566 <Index> was created with unknown prop 'errors' Index.svelte:79:92
```

[image: warnings in browser console]